# Google Sheets: Convert columns to x rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In Google Sheets, I have one line per purchase order. However, I need to convert it to x lines, where x is the number of products in the order.

See this picture, I need the top half converted to the bottom half:

[image]

It's not necessary that the name and address in the order is repeated (but it's okay if it is). It just needs to be in the first line of the order. It is necessary that the order number is repeated though. There are only 5 products, but some may not order all 5, so I'd prefer not every order have 5 lines, where item quantity would be 0 for those products they don't order.

How would I go about doing this?! I have a spreadsheet of 2000 orders and would like to automate/speed up as much as possible.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, another expert helped out. Thanks.

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(D2:H3,A2:A3&CHAR(9)&B2:B3&CHAR(9)&C2:C3&CHAR(9)&D1:H1&CHAR(9)&D2:H3&CHAR(10),)),,9^9)),,9^9),CHAR(10))),CHAR(9)))
```

Comment: For 2k records?

Comment: Yup, this formula, plus when I added a few extra columns e.g. &J2:J1931&CHAR(9) - worked beautifully! I had to account for some blank cells here and there to make sure the columns match up, but everything in working order.